# Adding new commands

Tags: 12.10, bash, 64-bit, gnome-terminal

I have added some new commands to `~/.bash_profile` but every time I start a new terminal session, it seems to forget these commands and I have to do `. ~/.bash_profile` again. Is there a way to avoid this doing every single terminal session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why ~/.bash_profile is getting overwritten, but I've had problems with it before too. Instead, use ~/.bashrc.

What I do is create the file `~/.bashrc2`. In that file I put all my custom commands. After you have what you want, edit `~/.bashrc` and add this line at the bottom:

```
. ~/.bashrc2
```

Even if `~/.bashrc` gets modified, it won't hurt your customizations. Now you have a portable customization file that you can take to any computer.